# Is there a way to get the object which instantiated the class inside the same class (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to obtain the object which instantiated the said class and pass it to another class.

say my code looks like this

```
class BestFriends():

class Friend():
    def __init__(self):
        bff = BestFriends()

def main():
    mainobj = Friend()
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
class BestFriends():
     def __init__(self, friend_obj):
        pass

class Friend():
    def __init__(self, selfobjfriends):
        bff = BestFriends(selfobjfriends)

def main():
    # Obviously won't work
    mainobj = Friend(mainobj)
```

So my question is how do I obtain the object which instantiated a class inside the same class? Once I obtain it, I believe I could easily pass that to another class that I require.

Comment: The easiest way if you control the class definitions would be to add an attribute referencing the object.

Comment: Pass it at time of instantiation.  There is no magic way, the link between those objects won't exist unless you create it yourself.

Comment: There is no object responsible for creating the `Friend` instance here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Could you please elaborate on how to do it without instantiating friend class twice?

Comment: @Piyush inside `BestFriend` `__init__` just have `self.friend_obj = friend_obj`. Then you can access your `bff_object.friend_obj`

Answer (score 1):

If what you're actually trying to do is create two objects that each reference the other, there are several possible solutions, but they will likely depend on the real world classes where you're trying to do this.

A very simple way to construct two objects that each refer to the other (using only one instance of each class) is:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar(self)

def main():
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo, "has a Bar named", foo.bar)
    bar = foo.bar
    print(bar, "has a Foo named", bar.foo)
```

If this doesn't do what you want, it might help to describe the original problem you're trying to solve, and then we can offer more specific answers.

Comment: Ahh completely forgot that self in Python refers to the object itself and I can pass it around using self. Thanks